# Report to show "My" Accounts but based off different User Lookup instead of Account Owner

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, custom-reports

We currently have an additional custom user lookup field on Accounts called CS Rep. I am trying to dynamically run the report as if I were the CS Rep. This way I can run a single report to send to each CS Reps through a subscription. It would work the same as using the My Accounts filter, but with the CS Rep field instead of Account Owner.

Is there a way to do this? Trying to find an alternative to making 10 different reports filtered by each CS Rep.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please take a look at this link, It might help you with solving the reports.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387687&type=1

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @senthamizh - That worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: Link is 404 now